# How to find the smallest possible 2 separate sums given a list of numbers while using the whole list?

Tags: algorithm, numbers

Given a list of numbers `5,10,15,25,35,45` how would you distribute the numbers into two separate sums such that each sum is the smallest it can be?

Manual calculations would lead me to believe this is the smallest two sums:

```
5+10+15+35 = 65
25+45 = 70
```

But you could also have the same result with

```
5+15+45 = 65
10+25+35 = 70
```

and several others besides. Given a different set such as

```
5.7, 10.2, 15.3, 25.6, 35.1, 45.8
```

The most optimal result would appear to be

```
5.7 + 15.3 + 45.8 = 66.8
10.2 + 25.6 + 35.1 = 70.9
```

There may also be additional sets with the same optimal sums in a situation like this (similarly to above) so finding all the possible sets of sums to get the same result would also be needed, though knowing the final sums would be sufficient for me to get the rest of the possible sets.

The best way I've thought of handling this would be to find the sum of the set and divide by two and then take every possible combination of sums and find the sum closest to the average, however I wanted to post here to see if there is a more efficient method.

What algorithm would be appropriate to use here and is there any example of this use case elsewhere on StackOverflow that I was unable to find?

Comment: Looks like a generalization of the Partition Problem, which is NP-complete. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_problem

Comment: @Henrik That's exactly what I needed! Thank you! You're welcome to post an answer if you'd like credit.